# Modelo de base de datos, Normalizacion

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, oracle, mariadb, modelorelacional

estoy diseñando un modelo de base de datos pero me surge una pregunta. Dado que desde hace un tiempo no diseño una desde cero, no se si para este caso es mejor crear unas tablas de detalles o se pueden colocar directamente el contenido de cada tabla de detalles como campos de la tabla estudiante.

[image: Modelo Relacional]

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Personalmente... si en cada tabla "Grados", "Generos", "Discapacidades", etc, vas a guardar un único String, yo lo pondría directamente en Estudiante y me olvidaría de la complejidad añadida de tanta tabla. Normalmente se normaliza cuando hay varios datos relativos a lo mismo, puesto que ahí se puede sacar una tabla externa que haga relación a esa cosa, por ejemplo si además de "Religion" tuvieses "Religion_es_monoteista", pues sí sacaría una tabla con ambos campos. Pero tener una tabla para un único string, no es normalizar, es añadir complejidad *gratis*.

Comment: Disculpa, que ocurre por ejemplo en Géneros, seria lo mismo crear dos registros Masculino y Femenino en esa tabla y que todo campo de la tabla Estudiante tuviera como llave foránea 1 o 2 a siempre que se registre un estudiante dejar que escriba ya sea M, F, Masculino y Femenino? En rendimiento algo cambia o como va lo cosa? Gracias

Comment: Hombre, ya no es cuestión de rendimiento... es que veo innecesario hacer un join a otra tabla para recuperar un único valor. Y claro que algo cambia en rendimiento, un inner join es una multiplicación de elementos. Si tienes 10 usuarios y cada uno tiene una religión diferente, por ejemplo, en realidad tienes 100 combinaciones posibles en tu base de datos, que tu join debe filtrar. Pero es que ya no es cosa de rendimiento, es por pura *facilidad* a la hora de hacer la query. No es lo mismo un `select * from user*  que tener que escribir 10 joins! Obviamente será mucho más lento con tanto join

Comment: Listo me quedó mas claro, una ultima duda, como las tablas que marqué en color rojo solo están relacionadas 1 a 1 con la tabla Estudiantes lo mas lógico seria agregar los campos de las tablas denominadas Detalles_.. directamente como campos de la tabla Estudiantes?

Comment: Ahí ya si que entra en juego la normalización, todos los campos que puedas agrupar y extraer a otra tabla deberías hacerlo. Aunque sea 1 a 1, te quitas 5 campos de la tabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que la respuesta estaría basada en si la relación es uno a uno o uno a muchos.

Por ejemplo Religión.

**Caso A**

Si el estudiante solo puede tener una religión (que quizá para éste caso sería lo más usual), no vale la pena crear una tabla nueva de detalle y es mejor dejar ese campo incluido en la propia tabla de estudiante. De hecho religión ni siquiera sería una llave y podría ser el texto tal cual.

[image: Tabla Caso A]

**Caso B**

Si el estudiante puede tener muchas religiones, entonces debes de crear una tabla nueva, esto te permitirá relacionar el id del estudiante con cada una de las religiones que podría tener y evitar repeticiones en la tabla Estudiante, para eso la normalización:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas dos tablas darían paso a una tercer tabla que incluirá el detalle sobre las religiones que cada estudiante puede tener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ésta tabla concretamente sería llenada con ids, de los estudiantes y de sus religiones, descritas ya propiamente en las tablas Estudiante y Religión. Así el contenido de tu tabla detalle_religion sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con amarillo marqué la parte que describe que el estudiante uno tiene dos religiones, la 1 (Protestante como en el ejemplo), y la 2 (que sería una más que también estaría descrita en la tabla Religión).

En resumen, si el detalle a describir del Estudiante puede tener varias instancias, entonces SI debes crear una tabla nueva de detalle. Si en cambio el detalle solo puede tener 1 instancia, se recomienda dejarlo en la tabla por simplicidad.

Edit: Debe de tomarse en cuenta que hay ocasiones en las que la relación si será uno a uno, como en la tabla Hogar_Detalles:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la que cada campo que ésta incluye son relaciones uno a uno, es decir, solo hay una respuesta para cada una como en los campos:

Integrantes
Numero_Hermanos

Si bien es factible que estos dos los pongamos directamente en la tabla Estudiante, en éste caso es correcto dejarlos como una tabla aparte para agruparlos por categorías, y así evitar tener una megatabla de Estudiante, en la que tendríamos que agregar dichos campos con una nomenclatura de éste tipo:
hogar_integrantes
hogar_numero_hermanos
hogar_hermanos_colegio
...

Y hay otro caso interesante: La tabla Salud_detalles:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí sería el mismo caso que Hogar, es bueno dejarlo como tabla por agrupación, pero aquí además tenemos dos campos en plural:

Enfermedades
Alergias

Por como está diseñada la tabla, se asume que todas las alergias que el estudiante tenga deberán ir en ese campo, sin nada que las separe, aquí el ejercicio correcto de normalización sería todavía crear una tabla más en donde se detalle las alergias o las enfermedades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde una tabla adicional, enfermedad_detalles, nos describiría que enfermedades tiene cada estudiante, una enfermedad por fila:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y un ejemplo de la información contenida sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde se indica en rojo que el estudiante 1, tiene Diabetes marcado con el id 3, y otra enfermedad más marcado con el id 4, cuya descripción también estará en la tabla Enfermedades.

Comment: Gracias me quedó mas claro, entonces veo que no es necesaria las tablas detalles hogar, detalles salud, detalles social, porque veo que un estudiante solo puede tener una instancia de estos.

Comment: Si son necesarias, y eso es algo que quizá debo agregar a la respuesta, aunque el estudiante solo tiene un "Hogar", como puedes ver, Hogar está compuesto por varias respuestas, como los integrantes, el número de hermanos, etc. En éste caso es importante usar la tabla de detalles para separarlos. Si bien podrías dejarlos como campos dentro de Estudiante: hogar_integrantes, hogar_numero_hermanos,  etc. Creo que en éste caso si sirve la tabla adicional, para agrupar por rubros, y que Estudiante no se vuelva una megatabla con demasiados campos.

Comment: Vale ya te entendí, muchas gracias. Por favor puedas añadir esa explicación a la respuesta para marcarla como la solución.

Comment: Claro, añadiré la respuesta y algunos ejemplos útiles sobre tus mismas tablas.